# Pronto CircleCI integration issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, circleci

Pronto fails to run in CircleCI build completes. I'm running Rails 4.2.9 and Ruby 2.4.0.

My circle.yml is:

```
test:
  override:
    - bundle exec rake test:all
  post:
    - if [[ ! -z $CI_PULL_REQUEST ]] ; then bundle exec pronto run -f github_pr -c origin/master ; fi
```

On running the pronto run command:

```
bundler: failed to load command: pronto(/home/ubuntu/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/bin/pronto)
Rugged::OdbError: object not found - no match for id (f61b491d0dbd5b3c13ad529587a06939fa1f54bc)
/home/ubuntu/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/pronto-0.9.5/lib/pronto/git/repository.rb:52:in `new'
/home/ubuntu/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/pronto-0.9.5/lib/pronto/git/repository.rb:52:in `blame'
/home/ubuntu/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/pronto-0.9.5/lib/pronto/git/patch.rb:17:in `blame'
/home/ubuntu/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/pronto-0.9.5/lib/pronto/git/line.rb:45:in `blame'
/home/ubuntu/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/pronto-0.9.5/lib/pronto/git/line.rb:20:in `commit_sha'
/home/ubuntu/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/pronto-0.9.5/lib/pronto/message.rb:18:in `initialize'
/home/ubuntu/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/pronto-rubocop-0.9.0/lib/pronto/rubocop.rb:49:in `new'
/home/ubuntu/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/pronto-rubocop-0.9.0/lib/pronto/rubocop.rb:49:in `new_message'
/home/ubuntu/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/pronto-rubocop-0.9.0/lib/pronto/rubocop.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in inspect'
/home/ubuntu/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/pronto-rubocop-0.9.0/lib/pronto/rubocop.rb:41:in `map'
/home/ubuntu/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/pronto-rubocop-0.9.0/lib/pronto/rubocop.rb:41:in `block in inspect'
/home/ubuntu/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/pronto-rubocop-0.9.0/lib/pronto/rubocop.rb:38:in `map'
/home/ubuntu/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/pronto-rubocop-0.9.0/lib/pronto/rubocop.rb:38:in `inspect'
/home/ubuntu/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/pronto-rubocop-0.9.0/lib/pronto/rubocop.rb:18:in `block in run'
/home/ubuntu/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/pronto-rubocop-0.9.0/lib/pronto/rubocop.rb:18:in `map'
/home/ubuntu/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/pronto-rubocop-0.9.0/lib/pronto/rubocop.rb:18:in `run'
/home/ubuntu/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/pronto-0.9.5/lib/pronto/runners.rb:20:in `block in run'
/home/ubuntu/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/pronto-0.9.5/lib/pronto/runners.rb:13:in `each'
/home/ubuntu/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/pronto-0.9.5/lib/pronto/runners.rb:13:in `run'
/home/ubuntu/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/pronto-0.9.5/lib/pronto.rb:64:in `run'
/home/ubuntu/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/pronto-0.9.5/lib/pronto/cli.rb:61:in `block in run'
/home/ubuntu/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/pronto-0.9.5/lib/pronto/cli.rb:60:in `chdir'
/home/ubuntu/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/pronto-0.9.5/lib/pronto/cli.rb:60:in `run'
/home/ubuntu/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/home/ubuntu/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
/home/ubuntu/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor.rb:369:in `dispatch'
/home/ubuntu/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/base.rb:444:in `start'
/home/ubuntu/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/pronto-0.9.5/bin/pronto:6:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/bin/pronto:23:in `load'
/home/ubuntu/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/bin/pronto:23:in `<top (required)>'
```

Any pointers on this issue would be super helpful! TIA.

Comment: did you installed pronto gem
it seems this file is having a hard time recognizing pronto which is used in the command